# Make git-svn work on Slackware 12.1

Tags: perl, git-svn, slackware

It is obviosly some Perl extensions. Perl version is 5.8.8.

I found Error.pm, but now I'm looking for Core.pm.

While we're at it: how do you guys search for those modules. I tried Google, but that didn't help much. Thanks.

---

And finally, after I built everything, running:

```
./Build install
```

gives me:

```
Running make install-lib 
/bin/ginstall -c -d /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i486-linux-thread-multi/Alien/SVN --prefix=/usr
/bin/ginstall: unrecognized option `--prefix=/usr'
Try `/bin/ginstall --help' for more information.
make: *** [install-fsmod-lib] Error 1
installing libs failed at inc/My/SVN/Builder.pm line 165.
```

Looks like Slackware's 'ginstall' really does not have that option. I think I'm going to Google a little bit now, to see how to get around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be compatible. The [CPAN Tester's matrix](http://bbbike.radzeit.de/~slaven/cpantestersmatrix.cgi?dist=Error+0.17015) shows no failures for Perl 5.8.8 on any platform.

Per the [README](https://metacpan.org/source/SHLOMIF/Error-0.17022/README), you can install it by doing:

```
perl Makefile.pl
make
make test
make install
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Base class package "Module::Build" is empty.
    (Perhaps you need to 'use' the module which defines that package first.)
 at inc/My/SVN/Builder.pm line 5
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at inc/My/SVN/Builder.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at Build.PL line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Build.PL line 6.
```

is a (rather poor) way of asking you to install [Module::Build](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Build).

Once you do that, it's

```
perl Build.PL
./Build
./Build test
./Build install
```

Answer (score 2):

> how do you guys search for those modules

http://search.cpan.org/

Comment: Actually, I did try that one, but http://search.cpan.org/search?query=core.pm&mode=all doesn't really help

Comment: Limit the search to modules: http://search.cpan.org/search?query=svn::core&mode=module

Comment: Don't add the .pm extension while searching. It is just there to help determine the type of the file.

Answer (score 2):

> now I'm looking for Core.pm

That’s SVN::Core, which is a bit of a problem. Try installing [Alien::SVN](https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien::SVN) from CPAN. That worked for me on my freshly installed Slackware 12.0 on my laptop, but I have yet to get it to install on my workstation.

Answer (score 1):

https://metacpan.org/ is your first port of call for Perl modules.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're running on Slackware so the cpan command is what you want to be using to install any Perl modules. It will pull in all dependencies for you. If you're running it for the first time it will have to do some cofiguration, but newer versions of cpan will ask if you want it to automatically configure it.

$ sudo cpan

cpan> install Alien::SVN

Additionally, if there's a package management application for Slackware, you should try that first to install new Perl modules.

Comment: Thanks. Slackware is a little bit specific regarding this (no sudo) and I don't see ready to use packages available.

Comment: You can shorten that command to just 'cpan Alien::SVN'. You don't have to drop into the CPAN.pm shell to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "does not seem to be compatible"?  Can you post the error message?

If the latest version does not work, you can select an older version in the "other releases" drop down and download that.

Edit:  to those reading this, the author updated the question, so my answer seems a bit out of left field :)

Comment: Obviously, I didn't know the correct way to install it, and copying file manually did not work properly. I managed to make it work using Michael's advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The place to search is http://search.cpan.org.

I have my browser (Firefox) set up so that I can type "cpan foo" in the address bar and it will search CPAN for modules matching "foo." You can do this with either a keyword bookmark or by assigning a keyword to a search plugin.